# Plot intersection of 2 functions in manim

Tags: python, plot, manim

I am trying to find the intersection of two graphs to plot in manim.

I initialize graphs like this:

```
g1 = axes.get_graph(lambda x: f(x),color=RED,x_range=[0,3])
g2 = axes.get_graph(lambda x: g(x),color=BLUE,x_range=[0,3])
```

Is there a general way to find coordinates of their intersection in manim, for any f and g? I want to plot it

Comment: If you already have functions `f()` and `g()` defined, why are you wrapping them with a lambda? Just pass them directly. Also, what exactly do you mean by "plot their intersection"? The intersection(s) will just be points... not particularly interesting. If you want to numerically find the intersection, you can use the bisection method, setting `f - g = 0` and finding the root(s).

Comment: @blorgon I iterate through multiple different f and g and show projection of their intersection as part of the bigger scene. Bisection is computationally costly for this use, so I was hoping there is some quicker method.

Comment: Bisection is crazy fast, depending on the functions and your initial guesses. As far as I know the only way to do this is to find the intersections numerically if you don't already know them *a priori*. There are other numerical methods as well (secant, Ridders', etc). There's really no shortcut if you don't already know the intersections.